Noise along certain direction of each instance
I have this simple node setup of a circle with 32 points and curve line instances on those points, where each one goes away perpendicularly from circle's center. We can a simple sun silhouette, if you like.
For each curvle line I've set 30 points with help of "resample curve" node to have some resolution for the next step, where I want to apply some randomness to each line in a way it become wavy/noisy by adding a "set position node" in combination with "Noise texture" node.
The problem is I don't know how to apply this effect along each curve normal. As you can see these lines go in defferent direction, and I want to use those exact directions. But, for example, when I try to apply noise along Y axis it affects all of them in a way thhat when noise getting closer to Y axis the curve lines there (top one and bottom one - highlighted in red) become just straight. And whe I apply it to both axis Y and X, then 45 degrees area (highlighted in red on the second screenshot) curves are getting straight.
I hope you got the idea, I just want to get the wavy/noise effect to each line, no matter what direction it goes. I think I understand why this undesirable effect happens, but I just don't know how wto set it up correctly.


